# How to link two reports in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, oracle-apex

Using oracle-apex 4,
I made report on these

**Tables**

```
airplane(plane_id,type,total_seats,starta,enda,startb,endb,startc,endc)

flight_shedule (flight_id,departure_dt,source,destination,arrival_dt) 

flight_seating_detail (flight_id,departure_dt,seat_no,class,fare,status)
```

I make `flight_id` column as a link column in `flight_shedule` report, when I click on that I want that it start filling values 
in `flight_seating_detail` report according to their own columns.

I have a code for that but how do I do that in Oracle APEX?

```
insert into flight_seating_detail 
with
 seats as (select rownum r 
             from dual 
          connect by level <= 350 
) 
select
     flight_shedule.flight_id, 
     flight_shedule.departure_date, 
     r seat, 
     case 
     when r between start_a and end_a then 'A' 
     when r between start_b and end_b then 'B' 
     when r between start_c and end_c then 'C' 
     end case
 from seats,
      airplane,
      flight_shedule 
where flight_shedule.airplane_id = airplane.airplane_id 
  and r <= airplane.end_c;
```

Comment: are the two reports in the same page or when you click the column link, it will redirect to another page that contains the other report?

Comment: You can run a process on page submit that will do the insert, then branch to a page which has a report based on the table you have inserted into.

Comment: i have reprts on different pages